# Laravel 5.4 - Where to change the id for login

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

During authentification it use the wrong id so i have this error :
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Field'id' unknow in where clause (SQL: select * from "acteur" where "id" = 22 limit 1`

The right id is : `id_biodiv_acteur`. And the model for the table `acteur` is User.php

So I made these change :

In `Authenticable`, `User`, `LoginController` i did `protected $primaryKey = 'id_biodiv_acteur';`.
In `GenericUser` i did this :

```
public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return 'id_biodiv_acteur';
    }
```

But it's not working. 
If in the table of my database I put `id` instead of `id_biodiv_acteur` it work, but i want to keep the right id.

Ask me if you need to see some code.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What should the primary key be?

Comment: It should be 'id_biodiv_acteur' instead 'id'

Comment: how have you set the primary key in the `acteur` model?

Comment: I changed $primaryKey like it say in the question

Answer (score 0):

In your user model which I think in your case is the "acteur" model you need to set `protected $primaryKey = 'id_biodiv_acteur';`

Comment: I already done it like i said in the question, sorry maybe i explain it badly

Comment: so in the `acteur` model you have set the primary key? in your question it says the `user` model

Comment: or is the `user` model linked to the `acteur` table?

Comment: It is the same, my User.php is the model for acteur table